# Traying to authentication and give user certain permission, depending on the type of user. But noting is happening

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-authentication, django-login

**Traying to authentication and give user certain permission, depending on the type of user. But noting is happening.
I try to limit access to certain functions on the site, depending on the type of user. But when I set a condition, nothing happens on the page:
This is my model.py**

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
 from django.db import models
 from django.urls import reverse

 user_type_choice = (('1', 'majstor'),
                    ('2', 'korisnik'))

 class CustomKorisnici(AbstractUser):
     user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,choices=user_type_choice)
     username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
     last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
     is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
```

**In the settings, I set: AUTH_USER_MODEL.**

```
 AUTH_USER_MODEL ='korisnici.CustomKorisnici'
```

**this is my login.html page. This part works ok.**

```
 {% extends "nav_footer.html" %} 
 {% load static %}
 {% block content %}
 <div class="form-group">
   <div class="container">
     <div class="form">
       <form method="post">     
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form.as_p }}
       <button id="btn" class="btn" type="submit">Login</button>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

**In my home.html page, I set condition for Users and here is a problem. **

```
   {% if user.is_authenticated and user.user_type == "korisnik" %}
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'post_page' %}">All posts</a>
       </div>
   {% endif %}
```

**First I set a condition if user.is_authenticated and this is working fine. After that just for checking, I add a condition if user.is_authenticated and user.username == 'admin'. When I log in as Admin or some other condition for username == 'John', it is working fine and link is visible.
But when I try condition user.user_type == "korisnik", link is not visible even when I login whit User how is user_type set to be korisnik. I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Do I need to do custom login function or something else**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value stored in the database is the first value of the tuple. Meaning from the tuple `('1', 'majstor')` the first value `'1'` would be stored in the field for users of type `'majstor'`. So in your template you should be writing:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.user_type == "2" %}
```

Also to make checking easy the best thing to do is to use constants in your model. So you would change your model like so:

```
class CustomKorisnici(AbstractUser):
    MAJSTOR = '1'
    KORISNIK = '2'
    USER_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (MAJSTOR, 'majstor'),
        (KORISNIK, 'korisnik')
     )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICE)
    # rest of the fields etc.
```

Now in the template checking would simply become:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated and user.user_type == user.KORISNIK %}
```