# Display user by filtering database in Django

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**I have two types of users in my model. And I am trying to get only one type of user to display on my HTML page. I am new to Django, so I am having some small problems. And place try to explain in a comment**

**This is my models.py file:**

```
class CustomKorisnici(AbstractUser):
    MAJSTOR = '1'
    KORISNIK = '2'
    USER_TYPE_CHOICE = (
        (MAJSTOR, 'majstor'),
        (KORISNIK, 'korisnik')
    )
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,choices=USER_TYPE_CHOICE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to="images/", 
    default='korisnici/static/post_user/images/profile_image.png')
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    bio = models.TextField(default=" ")
```

**After this a setup my view.py file for filtering data from the database:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .models import Post, TaskCategory,CustomKorisnici
from .forms import PostForm, updatePost
from django.urls import reverse_lazy,reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

class MajstoriView(ListView):
    model = CustomKorisnici
    context_object_name = 'majstori'
    template_name = 'majstori_view.html'  # html stranica na kojoj ce podaci biti prikazani

    def get_queryset(self):  # get_queryset biblioteka iz paythona
        return CustomKorisnici.objects.filter(user_type="MAJSTORI")
```

**A setup URL after that:**
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import MajstoriView

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('Majstori/',MajstoriView.as_view(), name="majstori_view"),
]
```

**And finally my HTML page.**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container>
  {% for majstori in majstori %}
    User name: {{ majstori.username }}
    Category: {{ majstori.first_name }}
    Tools: {{ majstori.last_name }}
    Budget: {{ majstori.bio }}</strong></p>
  {% endfor %}
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**I am trying only to display user with user_tayp = "MAJSTOR"**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traying to authentication and give user certain permission, depending on the type of user. But noting is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491318/traying-to-authentication-and-give-user-certain-permission-depending-on-the-typ)

Comment: I believe I have already answered this issue of yours in the above linked question of yours. To clarify **again** the first value in the tuple is the actual stored value in the db. i.e. you want to be writing `CustomKorisnici.objects.filter(user_type=CustomKorisnici.MAJSTOR)`

Comment: Thx: @Abdul Aziz Barka I am new in this. Why can I just put this: user_type="MAJSTORI", I was thinking if I set user_type, it will automatically search base for MAJSTORI

Comment: As I said the value stored in the database is the first value in the tuple. meaning `'1'` for a user of type `'majstor'`, meaning if you want to compare or filter you would write `CustomKorisnici.objects.filter(user_type="1")`. To reduce these magic strings we added a constant to the model itself which we use to compare etc.