# How can I check if a charfield result is something specific?

Tags: python, django

I want to check if Category in this method is Toys. Here is the method:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    CATS = (
        ("T", "Toys"),
        ("C", "Clothes"),
        ("B", "Baby essentials")
    )
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.TextField()
    Colours = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=CATS)
    Price = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    image_one = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='def.jpg')
    image_two = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='def.jpg')
    image_three = models.ImageField(upload_to='media', default='def.jpg')
```

What I did in the HTML template:

```
{% extends "ecomm/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for p in products%}
    {% if p.Category==Toys %}
       <p> {{p.Title}}</p>
       <p> {{p.Price}}</p>
       <p> {{p.Description}}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Make the toys as string, `'Toys'`

Comment: Still doesn't work:  
Could not parse the remainder: '=='Toys'' from 'p.Category=='Toys'' @starboy_jb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Traying to authentication and give user certain permission, depending on the type of user. But noting is happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66491318/traying-to-authentication-and-give-user-certain-permission-depending-on-the-typ) Also spaces are important in Django Template Language, because the parser splits on them, hence you need to write something like `{% if p.Category == 'T' %}`

Comment: It worked! Thank you. The spacing and 'T' were right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change the comparison to something like this, using the key and not the description of the category, and also putting the `T` as a string:

```
{% for p in products %}
    {% if p.Category == 'T' %}
       <p>{{ p.Title }}</p>
       <p>{{ p.Price }}</p>
       <p>{{ p.Description }}</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

This is because the field `Product.Category` holds the string value `T`, not the whole label `Toys`; the label `Toys` is added by Django code when rendering the HTML pages.

Comment: Yes This Should Work